# Routing in ASP.NET Web Forms Website

Tags: asp.net, routes, webforms

I am trying to implement routing mechanism into my ASP.NET Web Forms - Site. Unfortunately all tutorials on how to do it I can find describe ASP.NET Web Forms - Application scenario, with Global.asax file. I obviously do not have this file. What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the show all files icon on top of Solution Explorer and you should be able to see it.

Comment: Also, checked the website folder in windows explorer and global.asax doesn't exist

Comment: Bartosz, try this: http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/345082-asp-net-2005-where-global-asax

Comment: So can I just add global.asax to my website and it will like it was within application?

Answer (score 0):

you should look into the MVC design patten.

Comment: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/01/16/deciding-when-to-use-asp-net-mvc-framework.aspx

Comment: Please provide information as to why s/he should look into such a pattern.  As it stands, your answer has nothing to do with the topic, nor does your link-only comment.

Comment: MVC has an intrinsic routing mechanism readly built in, which is powerful and easy to use, giving good clean readable URLS, which I would imagine is the end point for the inital questioner.

Comment: I know, but this would force rewriting the whole application. I just need to replace url address of the website with a custom one.